# Is 90°C too high for GPU and CPU whilst gaming?

Tags: technical-issues, hardware, graphics-card

I have an HP laptop with Intel i3 5005u CPU and Radeon R5 M330 2GB GPU. When I play games both the CPU's and the GPU's temperatures get up to 99°C and mostly stay above 93°C. Should I continue playing with these temperatures? I mostly play Valorant on low settings and it gives me 40-60 FPS but I feel thermals are high.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: If we can have questions like [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/204332/is-my-gpu-temperatures-high-how-can-i-lower-it) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201147/gtx-970-running-at-80c-playing-arma3-on-singleplayer), why would this be off-topic? While the hardware used here is indeed not "game-specific", it is in the context of this question. Vote to leave open.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about generic computer hardware, not gaming.

Comment: For what it's worth, I consider both of the questions Joachim used as examples to also be off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Good idle GPU temperatures are normally expected to be around 40°C - 60°C. Whilst gaming this will likely rise up to 80°C.

90°C is probably too high for your GPU as temperatures over 80°C GPUs will start to throttle which will decrease their performance.

Of course, the temperature where you live will have a big effect on the temperatures and there isn't much that can be done about that. Things that could help are ensuring thermal paste has been properly applied (where applicable), there is good airflow through the laptop with fans functioning correctly and avoiding long high intensity sessions as the temperature will start to build over time with no breaks.

Comment: It sounds like this particular  laptop is an older model one too.  It could need a nice cleaning.  But keeping laptops cool in general when under heavy loads is a challenge.